# trouble installing Oracle Virtual Box Guest Addition in freeBSD 10.2

Tags: freebsd, virtual-machine

I am following a procedure on [freeBSD wiki to install Guest Additions in freeBSD](https://wiki.freebsd.org/VirtualBox).

```
pkg install emulators/virtualbox-ose-additions
```

I was able to install  emulators/virtualbox-ose-additions without any errors. After this I ran this command:

```
 # cd /usr/ports/emulators/virtualbox-ose-additions && make install clean
```

and got this error:

```
 vboxmouse_drv_117.so : No such file or directory
*** Error code 71
```

More details in image below:

[image]

Comment: You can try to install via package: `pkg install virtualbox-guest*` or `pkg install virtualbox-ose-additions` don't remember exact name

Comment: that is what I did, and did not get any error, I am having problem when I run `make install clean`

Comment: Then why do you want to install it from ports? If it didn't give any error, then you already have this package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're two ways of installing applications in FreeBSD:

- by installing a package using package manager `pkg`
- or by compiling it from `ports`

When you've run `pkg install emulators/virtualbox-ose-additions`, you already had installed it and there's no need to re-install it from ports.